# Quickly connecting to Wi-Fi with Android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, settings, archos-gen8

I'm having Android Froyo (2.2), in Archos 32.

The only way I found for connecting to a Wi-Fi wireless network is through

```
Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> Wi-Fi Settings -> "Wi-Fi networks" list
```

Very cumbersome! Isn't there a faster way to do it? After all the only internet connection Archos 32 has is the Wi-Fi...

Comment: Do you have it set to alert you when there are open WiFi networks available?

Comment: @AI I do. But it's not so convenient, as I can't control the exact time it's checking for new networks. Thus I can't easily adapt my position to gain enough reception for a WiFi network.

Comment: Are you connecting to a known network or a new network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few ways to do it on a Samsung Galaxy S.

- drag down from the notification area. Wi-Fi on/off is one of the controls.
- long press on the home screen, select `widgets` then select `Power Control`.  This widget also has a Wi-Fi on/off control.
- long press on the home screen, select `Shortcuts`, then `Activities`, expand `Settings` in the list that's displayed, then select `Wi-fi settings`.  This will take you directly to the page with the list of available Wi-Fi networks.

Hopefully one of these will help.

Comment: I think the Power Control widget came in Android 2.2 by the way. Older versions won't have that, but there lots of apps that do the same thing for older versions of Android.

Comment: @mufasa: I have Android 2.1 and have the power control widget.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Beautiful Widgets](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.levelup.beautifulwidgets), which provides a wifi toggle widget.

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought so, but I really don't need any way to toggle the WiFi connection.

Comment: I was probably projecting my own usage patterns, where the main operation is toggling wifi. When it’s on, it automatically connects to networks I’ve used before, and if there are new unprotected networks, a notification appears, so I rarely open the wifi settings proper.

Answer (score 2):

A "[Quick Settings](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bwx.bequick)" application by Sergej Shafarenka. It allows quickly toggling WiFi as well as a quick access to a bunch of other settings. It stays in the notification bar for a convenient access. Probably the most used application on my N1.

Answer (score 2):

You could also setup Locale or Tasker to turn on the wifi during certain times of the day.  So if you know for a fact you might be using your tablet during a certain time period, it could auto-turn it on during that.

Or if you look at it the other way, you can have it turn the Wifi off when you know for a fact you won't be using it (i.e. sleeping).

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is to download a WiFi app from Market; many are free.

I use [WiFinder](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pgmsoft.wifinder).

These seem to integrate pretty well with the Android Wifi and doesn't conflict (unlike the PC, in which you have Dell's Wireless Utility AND the Windows wireless, which you cannot run at the same time).  When I installed WiFinder, it knew that I was already connected to my work network, and it remembered my preferred network.