# Is there an app which will force reconnects on remembered in-range wifi networks?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, wi-fi

I'm having some difficulties with my San Francisco handset, running 2.1

It seems to keep dropping Wifi connection randomly. I've got the wireless router sat next to me, and its connected OK, but if I walk downstairs (still within range) it will drop connection.

At the moment I manually have to go to settings > wireless and force it to reconnect, this is quite annoying

Is there any app which will periodically check for in-range remembered networks, and force reconnects if possible?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/why-does-my-wifi-not-automatically-reconnect-to-prefered-networks http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2408/how-can-i-configure-my-phone-to-automatically-connect-to-remembered-wifi-networks http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/quickly-connecting-to-wifi-with-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto WiFi Toggle has been getting quite a lot of traction this past week and it looks like it may be what you're looking for.

It will search for WiFi networks in your range every interval (set by user) and then connect to them.

[Auto WiFi Toggle](http://www.appbrain.com/app/auto-wifi-toggle/com.appspot.eikatou0.autowifionoff):

[image: Auto WiFi Toogle QR Code]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my San Francisco. The WiFi wouldn't reconnect properly after the screen had woken.

Haven't tried 'Auto WiFi Toggle' but '[WiFi Auto ReEnabler](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-auto-reenabler/jp.sakira.wifireenabler)' set to 'Disconnect then re-connect' on wake seems to be working for me.

[image]